# How to determine the whether the transaction is conflict-serializable or not?

Tags: database, conflict-serializability

I've the following [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3z1Z.jpg):

```
read(T1, x)
read(T2, x)
write(T1, x)
write(T2, x)
commit(T1)
commit(T2)
```

> State whether the schedule is conflict-serializable, recoverable and avoids cascading abort?

I approach the problem like:

```
----------------------
|   T1    |   T2     |
----------------------
| read(x) |          |
----------------------
|         | read(x)  |
----------------------
| write(x)|          |
----------------------
|         | write(x) |
----------------------
| commit  |          |
----------------------
|         | commit   |
----------------------
```

I thought like, since there was no cycle (acyclic) in the precedence graph , it was conflict-serializable. Also transaction `T1` can be transformed to the  transaction `T2` by swapping:

```
----------------------
|   T1    |   T2     |
----------------------
| read(x) |          |
----------------------
| write(x)|          |
----------------------
| commit  |          |
----------------------
|         | read(x)  |
----------------------
|         | write(x) |
----------------------
|         | commit   |
----------------------
```

- Is it recoverable? I think yes, since `T1` commits after writing and `T2` reads, writes and commit.
- Is it cascedeless? I think no, since `T1` and `T2` are not committing after writing.
- Is it avoiding cascadeless abort? I think yes, since it is recoverable.

However, the answer is:

- Not conflict serializable
- Recoverable
- Avoids cascading abort

Now, why is this conflict-seriable?

- Most probably the answer is the cycle occurs between `T2` read(x) -> T1 write(x) -> T2 write(x).
- If I'm correct, then why the schedule 3 is conflict-serializable?

  - [image]

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought like, since there was no cycle (acyclic) in the precedence graph , it was conflict-serializable.

Wrong assumption. If we draw the precedence graph:

[image]

The schedule is not `conflict-serializable`

- ### Is it recoverable?

  - Yes. `T1` first writes to the `X` and first `T1` is committed.
- ### Is it cascadeless?

  - No. `T2` does not read the committed data.
- ### Is it cascading?

  - Yes. If there is a failure `X` can be reverted back to its original value.